# What's the use of getCollisionKey() in relayjs?

Tags: relayjs

I am new in relay and saw this on getCollisionKey on treasurehunt tutorial:

```
getCollisionKey() {
    return `check_${this.props.game.id}`;
  }
```

In the docs it states - Implement this method to return a collision key. Relay will send any mutations having the same collision key to the server serially and in-order.

Please help me understand what is getCollisionKey. Would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

`collisionKey` is an identifier to help know when mutations needs to be executed one after the other or when they can be parallelised.

Why we need this is mostly because of **network inconsistencies**.

Take for example a mutation `LikeOrUnlikePost`. This mutation likes or unlikes the post depending on if you already like it or not.

Suppose you like the post, then 1s after you decide to unlike.
But the first mutation fails, so it isn't sent to your server, so only one `LikeOrUnlikePost` mutation is sent.

The result is that you think you unliked the post (you clicked twice), but in fact you only liked it (only one mutation succeed).

This is what `collisionKey` is for. It tells Relay to queue any mutations which have the same collision key.

In the case above, what would happen is the second mutation would get queued, and would never get executed as the first one fails.